# VB.net Bulk Insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

Its regarding 'Bulk Insert' sql command where I having problem regarding some French Accents. The 'à' or 'a acute' is showing up as n++ in database table after I insert them from a text file. And this is the only character that is having problem with current conversion. I tried to modify the command using 'WITH' clause and assigning value such as 'RAW' or '1252' or 'ACP' but none of them were able to retain this particular character. The database I am using is Sql Server 2008. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

FYI, I aint using any encode or decode technique. Just trying to put whatever on text file back into database.

---

Thanks for the response. However, changing the column type to 'nvarchar' from 'varchar' didnt actually solve the issue. Its now appearing as '∩┐╜' in the database table column. Any idea people ?? Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: There's a character encoding problem going on here - ensure you're using UTF-8.

Comment: What datatype is the column that you're inserting the data into? It'll need to be nvarchar or ntext (although that's depreciated) in order to store unicode data.

Comment: There isn't any way you can store the french accent characters then. You'll have to change the column to nvarchar if you want to store them.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. However, changing the column type to 'nvarchar' from 'varchar' didnt actually solve the issue. Its now  appearing as '∩┐╜' in the database table column. Any idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Bridge says, you'll need `NVARCHAR`.  You'll also need to convert the file to UTF-16, as `BULK INSERT` does not play nice with UTF-8 even when you're using `NVARCHAR`.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498033/how-to-write-utf-8-characters-using-bulk-insert-in-sql-server) for more information.

There are several questions here regarding converting file encodings, but for the record this worked for me:

```
public static void  ConvertUtf8ToUtf16(string path, int bufferSize = 4096)
    {
    string  tempPath = path + ".tmp";

    char[]  buffer = new char[bufferSize];
    using (var input = File.OpenText(path))
    using (var output = new StreamWriter(tempPath, false, Encoding.Unicode))
        {
        int  index = 0;
        int  chars;
        while ((chars = input.Read(buffer, index, bufferSize)) > 0)
            output.Write(buffer, 0, chars);
        }

    // Swap the files
    File.Delete(path);
    File.Move(tempPath, path);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, changing the column type to 'nvarchar' from 'varchar' didnt actually solve the issue. Its now appearing as '∩┐╜' in the database table column. Any idea

Comment: That's not the whole solution.  What is the character encoding of your file?  `BULK INSERT` is touchy.

Answer (score 0):

Change the column type to `nvarchar`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. However, changing the column type to 'nvarchar' from 'varchar' didnt actually solve the issue. Its now  appearing as '∩┐╜' in the database table column. Any idea.

Comment: Addional information : I am inserting those French characters from a text file to database table. I am using Bulk Insert to do that. thanks

Comment: @Sanjay - that bulk insert file is not in UTF-16 and that is your problem.

Comment: So that means I need to convert the text file to UTF-16 before performing bulk insert, rite ??

Comment: byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("this is test string");
byte[] unicodeBytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Unicode, utf8Bytes);
Encoding.Unicode.GetString(unicodeBytes);

\n\nThis is what I am doing before the bulk insert. Output of Encoding.Unicode.GetString(params) are being used to write another text file. Still getting some garbage output. Could anyone tell me if I am doing anything wrong while converting to UTF16 ... thanks