# bulk insert doesn't work property

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

UTF-8 formatted txt file bulk insert into Sql Server Management Studio 2008 R2, nvarchar(50) coloumns, doesn't work properly.

[**This is the summary of the problem, step by step**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Yueb.png).

I can't implement Turkish characters although txt file is **UTF-8**, and column is **nvarchar(50)**

Comment: That's not a summary of the problem, that's a collection of screenshots. *Use your words* and tell us what you are doing and what's going wrong.

Comment: And just to short-circuit this whole thing, I am pretty sure that Bulk Insert does not support UTF-8.

Comment: There's a good discussion on this subject in this thread (read the all answers too). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498033/how-to-write-utf-8-characters-using-bulk-insert-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

Please use Unicode native format for export and bulk import as it described in http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189941%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server does not support code page 65001 (UTF-8 encoding). Try to change your code page.
Additionally, you may have trouble with your sql server collation configuration.

"**Data Types for Bulk Exporting or Importing SQLXML Documents**" section in the link stated below most probably solve your case.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx

You can try DATAFILETYPE options as described in above section.
Hope it helps