# Unicode characters in Listview c#

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, listview, unicode

Here is the thing:
I need to display japanese character in listview in a SQL operated database manager I am currently building for a friendly company. Tried to google, but all answers led me to nothing really. Instead of displaying characters it just does "????". Have a look:

[image: View]

but I am loading a properly displayed .csv file from a machine that has a japanese installed on it. Also its been saved as utf8:

[image: csv]

Font I am using is Meiryo UI. Tried Tahoma and the same thing is happening. Loading is being done including encoding:

3

And finally here's the code responsible for stuffing the data into a listview:

4

I would really appreciate if someone could help me. Thanks!

Comment: Rest of pictures here:
 "[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ctpna.png"
  "[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9lNM.png"

Comment: this is C# + XAML. Also the server has installed japanese language for non unicode programs and views these csv files just fine.

Comment: http://imgur.com/4Sf02YA - here is the program. Where do I check the heade in browser? Im kind of confused.

Comment: Oeps, XAML. I'm sorry. Try read data with StreamReader the option System.Text.Encoding.Default instead of utf-8.

Comment: Tried it now. Does not work

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/HgYAb - using DataRowView is not working well either - maybe this helps

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/WWcgO - when data is being saved to a file from program, it is being displayed incorrectly as "???"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this thing. While using SQL Server 2014 I simply forgot to change the collation encoding in database settings. It was set on Latin instead of Japanese-Unicode BIN. Thanks to Ben for pointing me right direction.

[Fixed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCMjX.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You are using a streamreader to open the file, but you are not using that same streamreader to read the data. Instead you are instructing SQL server to open it using the `BULK INSERT` command. Prior to Sql 2012 SP2, there was no support for UTF-8 in `BULK INSERT`.

If you are using Sql 2012 SP2 or above, you might consider Tom-K answer here:

- [How to write UTF-8 characters using bulk insert in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498033/how-to-write-utf-8-characters-using-bulk-insert-in-sql-server)

Failing that, you must either convert the file to UTF-16 before doing the bulk insert, or use another method.

Comment: Both method failed as loading displays question marks or gibberish. I will try to change SQL server to a newer version and see what happens